# Is there an associative list in the standard library?

Tags: agda

I am not confident enough to try proving properties about the AVL tree that is there, so I want to try something simpler. I could implement it on my own, but do not want to spend time doing that if it is already hiding in the library somewhere.

Comment: FYI, I think it's called an "association list" rather than an "associative list".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list of pairs and the notion of membership can then be encoded via `Any`.

Bits of a very basic library:

```
open import Data.List.Base using (List)
open import Data.List.Relation.Unary.Any
open import Data.Maybe
open import Data.Product
open import Function
open import Relation.Binary
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Relation.Nullary

AssocList : Set → Set → Set
AssocList A B = List (A × B)

private
  variable
    A B : Set

_∈_ : A → AssocList A B → Set
a ∈ abs = Any ((a ≡_) ∘ proj₁) abs

module Decidable {A : Set} (_≟_ : Decidable {A = A} _≡_) where

  _∈?_ : Decidable (_∈_ {A} {B})
  a ∈? abs = any ((a ≟_) ∘ proj₁) abs

  _‼_ : (abs : AssocList A B) (a : A) → Maybe B
  abs ‼ a with a ∈? abs
  ... | yes p = just (proj₂ (lookup p))
  ... | no ¬p = nothing
```

Comment: Yeah, doing it like this was my intention unless it turned out it was already in the standard library. Since this kind of answer is coming from you, I think I can safely assume that it is not. I'll accept this as an answer then.

Comment: Do not hesitate to open an issue listing the properties you wish you had for `Data.AVL.Map`.